# C++ Graph Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, breadth-first-search

My data set is a list of `Edge`s which are passed as a pair of integers. Based on that, I have the following graph implementation for BFS. Could someone please review my code and comment on errors/omissions/efficiency and other points.

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Graph {

private:
    int num_of_vertices;
    std::vector<int>* Adj;

public:
    Graph(int V){

        this->num_of_vertices = V;
        Adj = new std::vector<int>[V];
    }

    void addEdge(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>* > edge_list)
    {
        for(auto it = edge_list.begin(); it != edge_list.end(); it++) {
            std::pair<int, int>* p = *it;
            Adj[p->first].push_back(p->second);
        }
    }
    void BFS(int start)
    {
        bool* visited = new bool[this->num_of_vertices]();

        for(int i=0;i<num_of_vertices;i++)
            visited[i]=false;

        std::queue<int> queue;
        queue.push(start);
        std::vector<int>::iterator i;

        while(!queue.empty())
        {
            start = queue.front();

            visited[start] = true;
            queue.pop();
            for (i = Adj[start].begin(); i != Adj[start].end(); i++)
            {
                if (!visited[*i])
                    queue.push(*i);
            }
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 6):

**Pointer to vector?**

You have two members: a pointer to a vector (which you `new`, but never `delete`, which leads to several other problems) and its size. But you're already using a `vector`, so just do it twice:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adjacency_vector;

Graph(int num_vertices)
: adjacency_vector(num_vertices)
{ }
```

**Pointer to pair?**

Similarly, for `addEdge`, take a vector of pairs - not a vector of pointers to pairs - and by reference to const:

```
void addEdge(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> const& edge_list)
```

And then just use a range-based for expression to add them all:

```
for (auto const& edge : edge_list) {
    adjacency_vector[edge.first].push_back(edge.second);
}
```

**Pointer to bool?**

You see a trend here, hopefully. In your `BFS`, you start with:

```
bool* visited = new bool[this->num_of_vertices]();
```

But you never delete it, so you're leaking that memory. Prefer:

```
std::vector<bool> visited(adjacency_vector.size());
```

Also, this already sets everything to `false`, so you don't have to manually. Though your original implementation did as well.

**What does BFS *do*?**

This is a `void` function, that does something with local variables `queue` and `visited` - and then what? What as the outside observer do I get? This function needs to return... *something* of value to the caller. Otherwise, it's just spending time doing nothing.

Also, again, prefer range-based-for for the push:

```
for (auto child : adjacency_vector[start]) {
    if (!visited[child]) {
        queue.push(child);
    }
}
```

It's just much shorter.

Comment: If I change the definition of Adj to `std::vector<std::vector<int>> Adj;` then can I use this `Graph(int items): num_of_vertices(items), Adj(items){ }` Is it legal. Also where is the Adj created now and how is it persisted between function calls.

Comment: @Violet_ You don't need `num_of_vertices` anymore, the adjacency vector knows its size. I don't understand your other question - it's still a member variable.

Comment: My bad, figured it out. Though still don't understand one thing. Why don't we need to initialized the num_of_vertices member variable.

Comment: @Violet_ Because it'd be the same as `Adj.size()`

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is absolute evil, because it compresses data. See http://pastebin.com/PS41pvUH On contests, `std::vector<char>` is used instead

Comment: @user2136963 "Absolute evil"? Get a grip.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, why do you use a raw pointer for

```
std::vector<int>* Adj;
```

you can simply use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Adj;
```

equally efficient IMHO. At least use a smart pointer like e.g.

```
std:unique_ptr<std::vector<int>[]> Adj;
```

Also, you are missing a destructor that frees the memory allocated in the constructor. 
My former recommendations would make this superfluous.

---

Use the constructor member initializer list, rather than initializing class members in the constructors body:

```
 Graph(int V) : num_of_vertices(V), Adj(new std::vector<int>[V]) {
 }
```

---

Usually you don't need to dereference the `this` pointer inside the class like `this->num_of_vertices`. Do this only if there are ambiguities with class member variable names and parameter or local variable names.

---

```
 bool* visited = new bool[this->num_of_vertices]();
```

leaks memory, as you never call `delete [] visited`. Again use a `std::vector<bool>` instead, or use a smart pointer.

---

Using the same name for a variable, that is already used as class name, like `std::queue<int> queue;` isn't such a good idea, some compilers may get confused about such stuff.

---

Last but not least use better naming, something like `V` or `BFS` isn't very descriptive/meaningful.

Comment: When I use the initializer list `Graph(int items): num_of_vertices(items), Adj(new std::vector<int>[items]){ }` This is the error that I get, `47: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >'
    Graph(int items): num_of_vertices(items), Adj(new std::vector<int>[items]){ }`

Comment: @Violet_ You've been mixing something up here, the sample I've been showing was referring to your original code. If you change `Adj` to  `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you don't need the `new` at all. Just call `Adj.resize(V,std::vector<int>());` in the constructors body, to make `Adj` the desired size.

Comment: Ah got it. C++11 seems like a totally different language.

Comment: @Violet_ Totally different from what actually? `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` was already working pre c++11 standard.

Comment: I was talking about unique_pointer that you mentioned. Still don't understand smart pointers that well.

Comment: @Violet_ The point of smart pointers is they do the dynamic memory management for you. Using `new` and `delete` yourself is quite error prone and full of pitfalls. I'd recommend [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to dive in a bit deeper.

Comment: @Violet_ smart pointers of been part of the language for over a decade now. Admittedly they were in boost for a while; but without smart pointers your not really using C++ just a glorified version of C.

Comment: @LokiAstari Well, `std::auto_ptr` which was (besides boost or loki implementations) the only standard smart pointer before c++11, had it's flaws and drawbacks.

Comment: If you were programming without boost before C++11......